# Delay in for loop while playing mp3 file C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to give delay in for loop, While in for loop there is mp3 file is playing.
What I actually want to do, that every clip plays after 2 sec. There are total 10 clips.
 Here is my code

```
    for (int i=1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

            wplayer.URL = @"D:\Project C#\A-Z\" + i + ".mp3";

        }
```

Comment: Sleep is a very ugly way to do this as it makes your UI sluggish. The better way would be a timer set to 2 seconds.

Comment: what's actually going?

Comment: @jim Actually I want to play 10 mp3 files !

Comment: @Robert Can you give me the code please ?

Comment: I meant what the existing code results to...

Comment: By using sleep the whole thread gets stop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1000` millisceconds = `1 sec`. so change your code as below:

```
for (int i=1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

            wplayer.URL = @"D:\Project C#\A-Z\" + i + ".mp3";

        }
```

Adding Timer would solve your Problem:

**Step 1:**
Add a `Timer` object to your class as below:

```
Timer timerPlay = new Timer();
```

**Step 2:**

write a function to play the audio files.

```
private void playMyAudioFile(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
           //code for playing your audio file
        }
```

**Step 3:**
 subscribe the above function to the `TimerTick` event as below:

```
 this.timerPlay.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.playMyAudioFile);
```

functions which are subscribed to `Tick` event are notified/called for every Tick event of `Timer`.

**Step 4:** 
now set the `Timer` `Interval` as 2 seconds.
so that `Timer` will generate the `Tick` event for every 2 seconds.

```
 timerPlay.Interval = 2000;
```

**Step 5:**

here you can control the `Timer` by calling `Start()` and `Stop()` Methods.

start the timer by calling:

```
timerPlay.Start();
```

stop the timer by calling:

```
timerPlay.Stop();
```

Comment: yes it's not good practice to hang your UI.propably timer can solve your problem.

Comment: @daniyalahmad: i have edited my answer.please let me know if you need anything more.